# Doctrine 2 lazy loading issue in ZF2 project

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, lazy-loading

Ok so in one word : help !

There is something that I can't figure out. In ZF2 I am using the wonderful Doctrine Orm Module. Everything is perfect but today I discovered something weird.
I guess there must be some mistake of mine somewhere but I can't find. Or maybe there is something I didn't understand clearly in Doctrine 2.

I have my entities mapped. When I have a Many To One relation without specifying the fetch option, when I get one entity by calling the find() method on my repository, I can see that my attribute contains as expected an instance of the proxy class generated. But when I call the setter on that attribute, then it still contains the emtpy instance of the proxy class ???

It seems that Doctrine cannot get the instance linked to my entity. In my case, the entity I get from the find() method is the owner of the relationship.

If I specify the fetch option on EAGER in my mapping, then the call find() method returns an entity with the attribute containing as expected the instance of the class that is specified in the relation.

Has someone ever had the same problem ?

Edit :
Ok so I created a new ZF2 project to be sure that nothing interfere.
So I have two entities Group and User :

```
/**
 * Class Group
 * @package Application\Entity
 * @Entity
 * @Table("`group`")
 */
class Group
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="group")
     */
    private $users;
}

/**
 * Class User
 * @package Application\Entity
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="user")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer", options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinColumn(name="groupId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $group;
}
```

Of course I have all the getters and setters in both class but I didn't put them in the example to go fast.

And in my controller I do one very simple thing to test without the view:

```
$user = $this->serviceLocator->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->find(1);
var_dump($user->getGroup());exit;
```

The var_dump displays :

```
object(DoctrineORMModule\Proxy\__CG__\Application\Entity\Group)[367]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[362]
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[363]
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (Application\Entity\Group) => int 1
  private 'name' (Application\Entity\Group) => null
```

Of course I added in the database users and groups and I have one user with id 1 in one group in the table group.

Maybe I missed one option or something ? To configure the Doctrine module, I just followed the doc on github so here I gave the annotation driver and the directory for my entities and of course the database credentials.

Comment: It sounds like you're missing something fairly simple, but it's impossible to tell without more detail.  You could improve you question by showing some code, particularly the relevant mapping directives and your repository usage.

Comment: Ok I added some details : I created a mini project to be sure that every thing is clean. I put the code of my entities and my test. Once again, if I put fetch="EAGER" in the user entity for the group relation, every thing is fine. But without it ...

Comment: That looks good at first glance.  So, what happens next?  When doe "call the setter on that attribute, then it still contains the emtpy instance of the proxy class" happen?

Comment: This is how Doctrine works. By replacing entity classes with proxy classes Doctrine can delay the expensive task of querying for and hydrating that association until it is actually needed. Doctrine, by default, is fetch `LAZY`. If however, you use  choose the `EAGER` fetch option the actual entity class is returned. [Consider learning a little more about when to use it](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#association-proxies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally expected behavior because doctrine is *lazy-loading* your group entity. This is because all you do is this:

```
$user->getGroup();
```

I will try to explain why you only get a proxy here:

The `User` entity you already resolved from the database holds the identifier (in this case `id = 1`) for your group entity (this id comes from the `groupId` column in your `user` table). When you call `getGroup` doctrine only creates a proxy for your `Group` entity and sets its `id` to `1`. No need for database interactions so far.

Since you are not requesting anything else from your `Group` entity a proxy will suffice in this simple case. You will notice a difference as soon as you request another property from your group entity (any other direct property (a column in your group table) but the identifier). Try for example to call `getName()` on your group entity. This property is not yet loaded so doctrine will fetch the row with `id = 1` from the `group` table in your database and will load all the columns as properties (in this case there is only one) inside your group object and then it will return the value for the requested name.

So try once like this:

```
$user->getGroup()->getName();
```

And your output will be very different.

I hope this makes the behavior more understandable.

Comment: yes exactly. In fact today I decided to have a look at the proxy classes generated by doctrine and I could see that. I misunderstood the lazy loading way cause by reading fast, at first I thought that calling the getter on the relation was enough for doctrine to launch the lazy loading. But indeed it is necessary to access one attribute. Thanks for your explaination